# What is the best practice for Django project structure?

Tags: django

I would like to know if there is a best practice for the structure of Django projects.
In particular, where do you located the virtualenv folder for your project?

Do you think is better the following solution:

```
/myproject
    /myenv
    manage.py
    /mysite
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        __init__.py
```

Or do you think is better to have a folder with all environments, for example in the home directory:

```
/virtualenvs
    /myproject1_env
    /myproject2_env
    ...
    /myprojectN_env
```

Comment: Completely up to you. I do the latter, and either way I would keep the environment out of version control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like to use [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) to keep my virtualenv at the same place and easily access them. I can recommand you to use this :)

```
Features

- Organizes all of your virtual environments in one place.
- Wrappers for managing your virtual environments (create, delete, copy).
- Use a single command to switch between environments.
- Tab completion for commands that take a virtual environment as argument.
- User-configurable hooks for all operations (see Per-User Customization).
- Plugin system for more creating sharable extensions (see Extending Virtualenvwrapper).
```

I have no relation with this project, I just use it on daily basis and really like it. Hope it can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Yup, using virtualenvwrapper is the best practice to manage your project without interfering with your machine environment it's like creating your own environment or machine you can say.

I think Django has provide the best structure as we use daily without any interruption not even mentally and it's easy to handle, Everything is separated so well.

Yes and you can have many aaps under one project which may or may not be connected to each other depends on your requirement , configuration of all app under one project will be in settings.py which is in parent folder for   all apps.

Basically it's awesome what they have provided.I will suggest you to use default hierarchy, doesn't matter even if your working with big or small project.